# Mocha Thinks Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

This is my first day with TDD.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    should = require('should'),
    User = require("app/models/user");

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/altor-security');

describe('user data', function() {
  it('password should be different after changing password', function(done) {
    var old_password_hash,
        new_password = "12345678";

    return User.findOne({ email: "example@gmail.com" }).exec()
    .then(function(user) {
      old_password_hash = user.password;
      return User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id : user._id }, { password: new_password }, { new: true }).exec();
    })
    .then(function(user) {
      user.password.should.not.equal(old_password_hash);
      done();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      err.should.equal(null);
      done();
    })
  });
})
```

My test fails because it thinks that User.findOneAndUpdate method is over specified. But it does take three parameters, findCommand, update, and options.

Any ideas why it's failing though?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> My test fails because it thinks that User.findOneAndUpdate method is over specified.

Actually, no. It says that "resolution method" (ie the way your code tells mocha async test is done) is over specified.

You are using callback and returning a Promise so mocha can't tell when your test is done and if it is ok.

You need to either use `done` or return a promise. Not both.

Preferred way (return a Promise)

```
describe('user data', function() {
  it('password should be different after changing password', function(/*do not use done*/) {
    var old_password_hash,
        new_password = "12345678";

    // return a Promise
    return User.findOne({ email: "example@gmail.com" }).exec()
    .then(function(user) {
      old_password_hash = user.password;
      return User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id : user._id }, { password: new_password }, { new: true }).exec();
    })
    .then(function(user) {
      user.password.should.not.equal(old_password_hash);
    })
  });
})
```

OR

```
describe('user data', function(done) {
  it('password should be different after changing password', function(done) {
    var old_password_hash,
        new_password = "12345678";

   // do not return anything
   User.findOne({ email: "example@gmail.com" }).exec()
    .then(function(user) {
      old_password_hash = user.password;
      return User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id : user._id }, { password: new_password }, { new: true }).exec();
    })
    .then(function(user) {
      user.password.should.not.equal(old_password_hash);
      done();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      err.should.equal(null);
      done();
    })
  });
})
```